# Kartik editable column is not working on iPad and Mac

Tags: php, yii2, widget

I have a Kartik editable column in a GridView. When I go to that GridView, it continuously reloads the page. This issue only occurs on iPad and Mac.

Here is my GridView editable column code:

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
    'attribute' => 'diagram_name',
    'readonly' => !yii::$app->user->can('diagram/editdiagram'),

 ],
```

How can I stop reloading the page? It works fine on other operating systems.

Comment: Have tried  with different browser ?

Comment: It looks like [it's an issue](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/krajee/not_found_404_kartik_93/#comment-2061695242), but a little old. Not sure if fixed yet.

Comment: @scaisEdge  - I tried on different browsers ,it works well .The issue is only on ipad and mac.

Comment: @Edvin Tenovimas -Can you suggest me any other editable column widget for yii2

Comment: @manoj.kadlag I'm afraid there is a very limited amount of editable widgets... :/ I personally don't know any other.

Comment: @ Edvin Tenovimas - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this on IOS-8.4 and IOS-9.2. It works on IOS-9.2 and not version before that.

For this to work browser must support pushState. This available from IOS-9.2 and above.

http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

Regards.